# $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ when $I$ is a finitely generated ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

When $I$ is generated by only one element I find it easy to write down the set $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ to find ideals ecc... However when there are more generator I'm not sure how it works.

I think that if $I=(a,b)=(a)+(b)=:A+B$ we have
$$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(A+B) \cong (\mathbb{Z}[x]/A)/((A+B)/A) \cong (\mathbb{Z}[x]/A)/ \pi(B)$$

where $\pi$ is the canonical projection from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/A$, so $\pi(B)$ is $B$ viewed as an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/A$.

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x,3) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and the proof i saw was
$$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x,3) \cong (\mathbb{Z}[x]/(3))/((x,3)/(3) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x])/(x) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$$

and here is the first question: why $(x,3)/(3) \cong (x)$? Is it because i have to view $(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$ so the $(x)$ above should be $\pi((x))$?

with more generator is it still the same? for example if $I=(5,3x,x^2)$ can I say that $$\mathbb{Z}[x]/I \cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]/J$$

where $J=(3x,x^2)$ ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and so

$$\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]/J \cong ((\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]/)/(3x))/(x^2)$$

where $(3x)$ is viewed in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $(x^2)$ is in $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}[x]/)/(3x)$?

Is it correct or am I totally wrong? I don't think this make sense. I would then say that
$$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5,3x,x^2)= \{a_0+a_1x | a_0 \in  \{0,1,2,3,4 \}, a_1 \in \{0,1,2 \}, x^2=0 \} $$

but I am pretty sure that this is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your first question, the natural map $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(3)\rightarrow\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}}[x]$ is given by $p+(3)\mapsto\bar{p}$. So an element $fx+3g\in(x,3)$ is send to $\bar{f}x+\bar{3}\bar{g}=\bar{f}x\in(x)$. On the other hand, if $\bar{h}x\in(x)$ where $h\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ then $hx\in(x)\subset(x,3)$ is such that $hx\mapsto\bar{h}x$. Since its an isomorphism we must have $(x,3)/(3)\simeq(x)$.

The same happens with your other example. You need to have in mind the isomorphism theorem: if $J\subseteq I$ are ideals in $R$ then

$$\frac{R/J}{I/J}\simeq R/I.$$

Comment: ok thanks I got the first part. using the theorem in the second say $I= (5,3x,x^2)$ and now $J=(5,3x)$ we have $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I \cong (\mathbb{Z}[x]/J)/(I/J)$. first of all $I/J \cong (x^2)/J$ and for the other I can use again the theorem, so $\mathbb{Z}[x]/J \cong (\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5))/(J/(5)) \cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} [x] / ((3x)/(5))$. An element in  $((3x)/(5))$ should look like (for some $g=a_1+..a_nx^{n-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$) $3xg $ mod $ 5=3a_1x+..+3a_nx^n$ where $3a_i \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5 \}$ . I conclude that $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} [x] / (J/(5)) \cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ (???)

Comment: assuming i'm right, now i consider $I/J \cong (x^2)/J \cong ((x^2)/(5))/(J/(5)) \cong ((x^2)/(5))/((3x)/(5))$. So $(x^2)/(5)$ is the set of all polynomial with degree $\geq2$ and coefficients in 0,1,2,3,4. $((3x)/(5))$ is sthe set of all polynomial with degree $\geq1$ and coeff in 0,1,2,3,4 so $I/J \cong  \{0\}$ and so $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I \cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. Is it right? I'm not convinced

Comment: @Ale you need take care about quotients. For instante, when you write $I/J$ you are saying that $J\subseteq I$. So $I/J=(x^2)+J/J$.

Comment: @Ale also we don't have $(x^2)\subseteq(3x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ($3$ isn't invertible) so we just get $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(3x,x^2)$. You can identify this set with $\{a_0+a_1x\in\mathbb{Z}[x]:a_0=0,...,4 \ \mbox{and} \ a_1\neq3\}$.

Comment: ok I get that to write $I/J$ it needs to be $J \subseteq I$ to make sense but since in $I$ elements have the form $x^2f+3xg+5h$, in the quotient this element becomes $\overline{x^2f}$ where the overline means taking the class modulo $J$. Right?
I also don't understand where did you get $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(3x,x^2)$ :  is it $\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ or not?

Comment: Also in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is true that $(3x)$ is the same as $(x)$? since an element $f \in (3x) \subset \mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ has the form $f=3xh$ for some $h=a_1+..+a_nx^{n-1} \in \mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ so $f=3a_1x+..3a_nx^n$ with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ and this is the same as $f=b_1x+..+b_nx^n \in (x)$ where $b_i=3a_i$ is reduced modulo $5$ and the opposite direction is similar.

Comment: in other questions I read that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f_1,..,f_n)$ is just $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with the conditions $f_1=0,..,f_n=0$ so $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(3x,x^2)= \{a_0+a_1x \in \mathbb{Z}[x] : a_1 \neq 3\}$. is it true in general even with $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: @Ale yes, from isomorphism theorem we have $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(3x,x^2)\simeq\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$. And you are right when you say that $(3x)=(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ since $3$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. I don't know about your last question, but I think that it is true. It seems a good exercise.

Comment: ok now i understand way better, thanks. last question: if $(3x)=(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$  it should be $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(3x,x^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x,x^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_5$ so why you said $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(3x,x^2)=\{a_0+a_1x\in\mathbb{Z}[x]:a_0=0,...,4 \ \mbox{and} \ a_1\neq3\}$ that is taking $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ with added condition $x^2=3x=0$? this is essentially the reason why i asked the question above: it may be that in a quotient with  $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ you can just take $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and add the condition "generators=0" but with $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ it works out differently

Comment: @Ale Because I was wrong, sorry. Really $(3x)=(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ so you get $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]\simeq\mathbb{Z}_5$. $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a field whenever $n$ is prime so any elements which are coprime with $n$ are invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. It might implies differences when you take quotients.